# Google Analytics not working with my blogger site

Tags: google-analytics

- I'm using blogger.
- Using standard (Default) blogger theme.
- I put analytics code in the head tag.
- [Analytics not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8M6y.png) for more than one month, although I receive visits & I see it on my articles!
- The strange thing, the real time report is working when I visit the site, it counts "1", so why the rest of analytics not working?
- I checked Google Chrome errors & I didn't find errors, but in Microsoft Edge, [I found this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdhXR.jpg)   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT     www. google-analytics. com/analatics .js:1

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that problem was in the Google Analytics account.
I removed the data, property & account from Google Analytics (Admin settings), then I created a new one, to get a different property ID & script code.

Comment: You may have had a bad filter applied in the settings for the previous property.  That would explain it.